# wsdl: type * not declared

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, wsdl

It seems that the nested element with a custom defined type doesn't work in visual studio 2008. I have the following wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd"
 xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
 xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:ns0="http://processmaker.com"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
 targetNamespace="http://processmaker.com">
  <wsdl:types>
     <xs:element name="processListStruct" >
        <xs:complexType >
          <xs:sequence >
            <xs:element name="guid" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="processListResponse" >
        <xs:complexType >
          <xs:sequence >
            <xs:element name="processes" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ns0:processListStruct"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
</wsdl:types>
<!-- snip other definition -->
</wsdl:definitions>
```

However inside Visual studio I got a "**type processListStruct not declared error**" when I navigated my mouse cursor over the line `<xs:element name="processes" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ns0:processListStruct"/>` . And as I wanted to generate the proxy class using the following command,

```
wsdl /out:mycsclass.cs blahblah.wsdl
```

I got an error saying that

```
The datatype 'http://processmaker.com:processListStruct' is missing.
```

How to fix this, and is there any other tool besides wsdl that can successfully transform the above element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is a wsdl.exe bug and I have reported [this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=470310) to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft responded, it's not a WSDL.EXE bug, it's a bug in the schema:

```
<xs:element name="processes" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ns0:processListStruct"/>
```

Yet, as we can see:

```
<xs:element name="processListStruct" >
```

`processListStruct` is an element, not a type.

Comment: But the wsdl should be able to distinguish between element and type, even though they have the same name.

Comment: No. It's not WSDL that's the problem. The XML schema is simply bad. You said type=, but it's an element. They are not the same thing.